# MongoDB $where is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I have looked around and tried all kinds of docs to be able to get the `$where` clause in MongoDB to work for me, but it just won't work.

Here is my object:

```
var UserProfiles = [{
userProfileID: "3f8c553c-3633-4fe9-a007-4346a783450c",
firstName: 'Austin',
lastName: 'Hunter',
email: 'ahunter8....com',
token: '',
platform: '',
password: 'admin',
companyProfileID: "86660a5b-7f61-4238-889d-1cc3087947b9",
authentication: ''
```

}....

there are several "profiles" inserted into the UserProfiles Object. That is just the first one.

Here is me inserting into the collection:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("We are connected");
    }

    var collection = db.collection('UserProfile');

    for (var i = 0; i < UserProfiles.length; i++) {
        collection.insert(UserProfiles[i], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }   
    db.close();
});
```

Now I am trying to search my collection for a passed in email AND companyProfileID. If they both match then return that profile. I thought the `$where` clause would be best but I can't get it to work.

Here is me trying to find():

```
function getUserProfile(passInEmail, companyID, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("We are connected");
        }
        var collection = db.collection('UserProfile');
        collection.find({$where: "this.email == passInEmail"}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
            } else if (result.length) {
                console.log(result);
                callback(result);
            } else {
                callback(err);
                console.log("No document found");
            } 
        });
        db.close();
    });
    }
```

I am trying to search the collection and if the object email matches the passed in email and the object companyProfileID matches the passed in companyID then success.

Comment: should be `this.email == 'passInEmail'` or `this.email.indexOf('passInEmail') == 0`

Comment: Ok. MongoClient find return a cursor than you can loop with the object returned by `collection.find({$where: "this.email == passInEmail"})`  OR you can use toArray : `collection.find({$where: "this.email == passInEmail"}).toArray( function (){ } )`

Comment: Still No document found. I got a `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error.

Comment: using `collection.find({$where: "this.email == passInEmail"}).toArray( function (result){
    console.log(result); 
} )`

I get:

name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'ReferenceError: passInEmail is not defined. 
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'ReferenceError: passInEmail is not defined :\n_funcs1@:1:24\n',
  code: 139

Comment: Yes because should be `"this.email == 'passInEmail'"`. Sorry i wrong copy and paste from your code

Comment: Okay That changed things. It is now throwing an error:

message: `$where got bad type`,

code: 2

Comment: ok sorry i write below a simple solution without using $where that in this case is totally useless

Comment: Thanks. I just assumed it would be best but I am up for other options. Im new to Mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$where` clause in your case in not the best thing.
You should do simply:

```
//userIdParam ad emailParam are two variables 
collection.find({userProfileID: userIdParam, email: emailParam})
    .toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else if (result.length) {
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
        } else {
            callback(err);
            console.log("No document found");
        } 
    });
```

Take a look of the doc [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html)

Comment: Thank you for a solution. Will this method make sure that userProfileID AND email both match the element?

Comment: Yes of course! every key in the json query are in AND. If you want to do, for example an OR you should write something like `{ query1:'query1', query_or:{ $or:['first', 'second'] }}` and the result is `query1=='query1' && (query_or == 'first' || query_or == 'second)`

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is working perfectly. Great work. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: it's a pleasure but please.. read the doc of mongodb.. it's a great db and you should know it better! The aggregation framework it's amazing! :) Bye